# Get all file after operation and rename them

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a "for" where I create some files with extension ".part". The files are added to a map. The next "for" is used to write info in every file. I need an operation that takes all the files after from that Map and rename every file extension from .part into .txt.  I let my code below.

Map variable

```
final Map<String, FileWriter> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
```

create file for every location

```
for (final ArabesqueDlvLocationModel locatie : localitati) {
        final File file;
        if (BooleanUtils.isTrue(judete.get(locatie.getCounty()))) {
            file = new File(folderPath + "/feed-facebook_" + locatie.getCounty() + "_" + locatie.getLocation() + ".part");
        } else {
            file = new File(folderPath + "/feed-facebook_" + locatie.getCounty() + ".part");
        }

        try {
            final FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, false);
            fileWriter.append(HEADER).append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
            fileMap.put(locatie.getCode(), fileWriter);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Write in every file

```
    for (final ProductModel product : products) {
        String productImageUrl = embrace(getProductImageUrl(product));
        if (validProductForFeed(product, productImageUrl, ignoredProducts, ignoredCategories)) {
            final String productCode = embrace(product.getCode());
            final String productName = embrace(getProductName(product));
            final String productDescription = embrace(getProductDescription(product));
            final String productCategoryName = embrace(getCategoryName(product));
            final String availability = embrace("in stock");
            final String condition = embrace("new");
            final String productUrl = embrace(getProductUrl(product));
            final String productBrand = embrace(getBrand(product));
            final String productGoogleCategory = embrace(getGoogleCategory(product));

            final StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
            strB.append(productCode).append(SEMICOLON);
            strB.append(productName).append(SEMICOLON);
            strB.append(productDescription).append(SEMICOLON);
            strB.append(productCategoryName).append(SEMICOLON);
            strB.append(productUrl).append(SEMICOLON);
            strB.append(productImageUrl).append(SEMICOLON);
            strB.append(condition).append(SEMICOLON);
            strB.append(availability).append(SEMICOLON);

            for (final ArabesquePlantModel plant : defaultPlants) {
                final List<ArabesqueDlvLocationModel> locationList = plantMap.get(plant.getName());
                final List<PriceInformation> priceInformationList = getPriceService().getPriceInformationsForProduct(product);
                final Map<String, String> priceMap = getPriceMap(product, priceInformationList, plant);

                if (!priceMap.isEmpty()) {
                    final String productDefaultPrice = embrace(getProductPrice(priceMap, DEFAULT));
                    final String productPromoPrice = embrace(getProductPrice(priceMap, PROMO));
                    final Long highestStock = arabesqueCommerceStockService.getStockLevelForProductSalesUnit(product, plant);
                    final boolean inStock = highestStock >= 1;
                    if (inStock) {
                        for (final ArabesqueDlvLocationModel location : locationList) {
                            final StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(strB.toString());

                            strBuilder.append(productDefaultPrice).append(SEMICOLON);
                            strBuilder.append(productPromoPrice).append(SEMICOLON);
                            strBuilder.append(productBrand).append(SEMICOLON);
                            strBuilder.append(productGoogleCategory);
                            try {
                                fileMap.get(location.getCode()).append(strBuilder).append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
                            } catch (final IOException e) {
                                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here i think i need to rename all files

```
    for (final FileWriter fileWriter : fileMap.values()) {

        try {
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I added

```
final File dir = new File(folderPath);

for(File file : dir.listFiles()){
        int index = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
        String nameWithoutExtension = file.getName().substring(0,index);
        file.renameTo(new File(folderPath + "/" + nameWithoutExtension + ".csv"));
    }
```